# How to convert entire dataframe to numeric while preserving decimals?

Tags: r, dataframe, numeric

I have a mixed class dataframe (numeric and factor) where I am trying to convert the entire data frame to numeric.  The following illustrates the type of data I am working with as well as the problem I am encountering:

```
> a = as.factor(c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04))
> b = c(2,4,5,7)
> df1 = data.frame(a,b)
> class(df1$a)
[1] "factor"
> class(df1$b)
[1] "numeric"
```

When I try and convert the entire data frame to numeric, it alters the numeric values.  For example:

```
> df2 = as.data.frame(sapply(df1, as.numeric))
> class(df2$a)
[1] "numeric"
> df2
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 4
3 3 5
4 4 7
```

Previous posts on this site suggest using `as.numeric(as.character(df1$a))`, which works great for one column.  However, I need to apply this approach to a dataframe that may contain hundreds of columns.

**What are my options for converting an entire dataframe from factor to numeric, while preserving the numeric decimal values?**

The following is the output I would like to produce where `a` and `b` are numeric:

```
     a b
1 0.01 2
2 0.02 4
3 0.03 5
4 0.04 7
```

---

I have read the following related posts, although none of them apply directly to this case:

1. [How to convert a factor variable to numeric while preserving the
   numbers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538084/how-to-convert-a-factor-variable-to-numeric-while-preserving-the-numbers-in-r) This references a single column in a dataframe.
2. [converting from a character to a numeric data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717217/converting-from-a-character-to-a-numeric-data-frame).  This post
   does not take into account decimal values.
3. [How can i convert a factor column that contains decimal numbers to
   numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299991/how-can-i-convert-a-factor-column-that-contains-decimal-numbers-to-numeric).  This applies to only one column in a data frame.

Comment: Great way to ask a question. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206700/sum-on-a-factor-column-returns-incorrect-result) may be helpful. This is a common source of frustration with `factor` variables.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You might need to do some checking.  You cannot safely convert factors directly to numeric.  `as.character` must be applied first.  Otherwise, the factors will be converted to their numeric storage values.  I would check each column with `is.factor` then coerce to numeric as necessary.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) {
    if(is.factor(x)) as.numeric(as.character(x)) else x
})
sapply(df1, class)
#         a         b 
# "numeric" "numeric"
```

Comment: Or do it outside the loop: `is_factor <- vapply(df1, is.factor, logical(1)); df1[is_factor] <- ...`

Comment: @hadley - I've been wondering about this.  It is more efficient to check first, and then run the change on the subset? Rather than checking inside the `lapply` loop?

Comment: Given the size of typical dataset I doubt it would make much difference

Answer (score 33):

Using `dplyr` (a bit like sapply..)

```
df2 <- mutate_all(df1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

which gives:

```
glimpse(df2)
Observations: 4
Variables: 2
$ a <dbl> 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04
$ b <dbl> 2, 4, 5, 7
```

from your df1 which was:

```
glimpse(df1)
Observations: 4
Variables: 2
$ a <fctr> 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04
$ b <dbl> 2, 4, 5, 7
```

Answer (score 10):

```
df2 <- data.frame(apply(df1, 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
> df2 <- data.frame(sapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
> df2
     a b
1 0.01 2
2 0.02 4
3 0.03 5
4 0.04 7
> sapply(df2, class)
        a         b 
"numeric" "numeric"
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but won't this convert a numeric column to character then back to numeric again?

Comment: @RichardScriven think that's right. I think my answer suffers from the same issue, though I don't think it's particularly problematic.

Comment: @n8sty No, it's not problematic at all, but it seems a bit wasteful.