# Code for converting entire data frame to numeric

Tags: r

Is there an R function to convert the entire data frame to numeric. My data frame contains only numeric variables but when queried with r with the is.numeric code, it comes as false.

Comment: Read about `?type.convert`. Also, please share a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert entire dataframe to numeric while preserving decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391921/how-to-convert-entire-dataframe-to-numeric-while-preserving-decimals)

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
df1[]<-  lapply(df1, as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` :

`mutate_all(data, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`